# How to get spacing between border and inner background color of a pie chart using highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

By using the below code i got Pie chart as shown in this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdyYA.png
But i need to get Pie Chart as shown in this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EscA8.png

```
Here is my code:
```

var highchartGraph = {

bindpieChart : function(percentage_c)
{

$('.piechart').highcharts({

```
            chart: {
            spacingBottom: -8,
            spacingTop: -8,
            spacingLeft: -8,
            spacingRight: -8,
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: true,
            type: 'pie',
            width: null,
            height: null,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
        },
        title: {
            text: percentage_c+'%',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            style: {
                color: '#FFF',
                fontSize: '18px',
                fontFamily: 'arial'
            },
            y: 3,
            x: 20
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function() {                                                 
                    },
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false,
                        brightness: 0
                    }
                }
            },
            pie: {
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderColor: "#6821A5"
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: " ",
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: "Unrestricted",
                y: percentage_c,
                color: '#6821A5',
                tooltip: false
            }, {
                name: "Restricted",
                y: 100 - percentage_c,
                color: '#FFF',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }]
        }]
    });
}
```

}

Comment: What you need is what you have judging from the images. Could you fix you question to have two different images and add a working live demo?

Comment: I have edited my question by providing the proper links for images can you check it once and give me the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add another series that will create the border.

`Demo`: http://jsfiddle.net/rxp0noj5/

```js
var percentage_c = 75;

$('#container').highcharts({
  chart: {
    spacingBottom: -8,
    spacingTop: -8,
    spacingLeft: -8,
    spacingRight: -8,
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: true,
    type: 'pie',
    width: null,
    height: null,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
  },
  title: {
    text: percentage_c + '%',
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    style: {
      color: '#FFF',
      fontSize: '18px',
      fontFamily: 'arial'
    },
    y: 3,
    x: 20
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function() {},
      },
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: false,
          brightness: 0
        }
      }
    },
    pie: {
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: "none"
    }
  },
  series: [{ // series for border
   innerSize: '100%',
   data: [1],
    borderColor: 'red'
  },{
    size: '95%', // decresed size for padding between pie and border
    name: " ",
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
      name: "Unrestricted",
      y: percentage_c,
      color: '#6821A5',
      tooltip: false
    }, {
      name: "Restricted",
      y: 100 - percentage_c,
      color: 'none',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```